# git submodule conflicts during rebase causes commit to disappear

Tags: git, conflict, git-submodules, git-rebase

I have this following scenario that keeps coming back:

1. I commit a change in some files, along with an update to a submodule.
2. Someone else commits and pushes an update to the same submodule.
3. `git pull --rebase`, I get a conflict
4. I fix the conflict by adding the latest version of the submodule.
5. **THE PROBLEM:** Now, instead of the commit I made at step #1, I have a commit with ONLY the update to the submodule, without the other file changes.

I always fix this by either aborting rebase and using pull --no-rebase, or by cherry-picking the commit before rebase from the reflog.

There must be a better way.

Is there a good workaround for this common buggy scenario?

Comment: Please refrain from using vulgar and offensive language on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the commands you run right after `git pull --rebase`?

Comment: After the `git pull --rebase` all my changes except the submodule update are already gone unless I `git rebase --abort`. I can run `git add <submodule path>; git rebase --continue` but then I'll have a rebased commit with only the submodule update without the other changes.

Comment: Try upgrading your git. Can't reproduce this. Have a commit that has both files changed and a submodule change where submodule has a conflict, and rebase behaves correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Evgeny - upgrading git solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a bug with an older version of git. Upgrading to a newer stable version is always a good idea when trying to fix weird stuff happening in software.

Comment: Thanks. My git installation came from Xcode so upgrading to Xcode 5 did the trick (lazy me...) :)

Comment: Use brew. Highly recommended. Or even boxen.

Comment: Was having the same problem (git 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)), upgrading to 1.9.0 fixed the problem